# Multi-use widget not saving/throwing error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have been trying to create a custom widget in Wordpress that saves it's settings independant of other instances of the widget. The site has multiple sidebars and the widget is used differently in each. I've followed [this tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28) and compared my attempt with the one to download there (aside from changes I need) and although that one works, mine doesn't.

One of two things happen when I tinker with it. a) Either it does nothing and just returns blank without saving, after hitting save. Or b) I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: exampleWidget-2 in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.co.uk/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php
>   on line 1636

The difference is whether I use a captial in the id-base variable. I am quite new to this side of Wordpress so that might make a difference with how you response.

```
/* Add our function to the widgets_init hook. */
add_action('widgets_init', 'load_tile_widget');

/* Function that registers our widget. */
function load_tile_widget() {
    register_widget( 'tile_widget' );
}


class tile_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function tile_widget() { 
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'example', 'description' => __('An example widget that displays a person\'s name and sex.', 'example') );

        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'exampleWidget' );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'exampleWidget', __('Example Widget', 'example'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );

    } // end function tile_widget()



    function widget($args, $instance){

        extract( $args );

        /* User-selected settings. */
        $tileTitle = $instance['tileTitle'];
        $tileText = $instance['tileText'];
        $tileUrl = $instance['tileUrl'];
        $tileColor = $instance['tileColor'];

        /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $before_widget;

        echo '<a class="tile tile-med" href="'.stripslashes($tileUrl).'" style="background: '.stripslashes($tileColor).'">';
            echo '<div class="tile-content">';
                echo '<h2>'.stripslashes($tileTitle).'</h2>';
                echo '<p>'.stripslashes(nl2br($tileText)).'</p>';
            echo '</div>'; //close tile-content
        echo '</a>'; //close url

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['tileTitle'] = strip_tags($new_instance['tileTitle']);
        $instance['tileText'] = strip_tags($new_instance['tileText']);
        $instance['tileUrl'] = strip_tags($new_instance['tileUrl']);
        $instance['tileColor'] = strip_tags($new_instance['tileColor']);

        return $instance;

    }

    function form($instance) {

        /* Set up some default widget settings. */
        $defaults = array( 'tileTitle' => 'Example Title', 'tileText' => 'Example Text', 'tileUrl' => 'http://example.org', 'tileColor' => '#aaccee' );
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

        <p>Tile Title: (Medium)<br />
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileTitle' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['tileTitle']; ?>" /></p>

        <p>Tile Text:<br />
        <textarea class="widefat" rows="5" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileText' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileText' ); ?>"><?php echo $instance['tileText']; ?></textarea></p>

        <p>Tile Link URL:<br />
        <input type="text" class="widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileUrl' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileUrl' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['tileUrl']; ?>" /></p>

        <p>Tile  Colour:<br />
        <input type="text" class="color-field widefat" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileColor' ); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileColor' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['tileColor']; ?>" data-default-color="#723e52" /></p>

        <?php
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'tileText' ); ?>">
```

should of been:

```
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'tileText' ); ?>">
```

Simple copy paste error. Shame I only realised about 6 hours later...

Thanks.